# Java no autoboxing for int for compareTo method?

Tags: java, int, compareto, autoboxing

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 1;
        int b = 5;

        Integer c = new Integer(1);
        Integer d = 5; //autoboxing at work

        System.out.println(c.compareTo(d));
        System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));
    }
}
```

Why doesn't `a.compareTo(b)` compile (`int cannot be dereferenced`)?  I know that `compareTo` requires objects, but I thought autoboxing would automatically make an `int` an `Integer` when necessary.  Why doesn't autoboxing occur in this case?  And what other cases will it not occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Oracle tutorial on Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), the two cases where boxing will occur are, when primitives are:

- Passed as a parameter to a method that expects an object of the corresponding wrapper class.
- Assigned to a variable of the corresponding wrapper class.

The expression being evaluated in your example (`a.compareTo(d)`) does not fall in any one of those scenarios.

Theres some interesting additional information in the [JCP proposal for autoboxing](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/autoboxing.html), describing the mechanics and rules for assignment conversion, method invocation conversion, and casting conversion.